# capturing "'this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, this, chaining

I created a chain API from online resources and I understand it except for one thing, I'm storing "this" in a variable-why? I'm hearing its to capture this to protect it, I'm not entirely sure what that means. Why I'm trying to protect "this" and why I'm a storing it in a variable, what does storing it in a variable do? How does this change "this"? I've done a quick search on here and on google and haven't found an answer. thanks

```
function Calc(value){
    let self= this;//captures this?
    self.value=value;//sets the initial value;

    self.add=function(addVal){
        self.value+=addVal;
        return self;
    }

    self.sub=function(subVal){
        self.value-=subVal;
        return self;
    }
    self.mult=function(multVal){
        self.value*= multVal;
        return self;
    }

    self.div=function(subVal){
        self.value/= subVal;
        return self;
    }
}

let cal= new Calc(10);

cal.add(2).mult(2).sub(2).div(2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: The code shown would produce the same result if you used `this` everywhere that you currently have `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really *storing* `this` in a variable, you're just storing a **reference** to the `this context variable` in a variable. That is fine but important difference.
Why you do it? Well, `this` is a dynamic reference which always references the current *context*. A new *context* (or more precisely an *Environment Record*) is created if you invoke a new function for instance.

So if you wouldn't store the reference from your outer context `function Calc`, you could not access it within your sub context's (`add, sub, mult, div`) because each of those has it's own `this` reference.

Comment: Except that if we changed that code to use `this` everywhere instead of `self` it would still produce the same result, because of the way the functions are being called.

Comment: True. The type of invocation decides the reference of `this` unless it was bound otherwise. I just didn't want to go into greater detail. In general, it is most important here to understand the dynamic nature of `this` for the OP imo.